# XSLT conversion with a hierarchy of XSL files

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

So I'm attempting to convert an XML file to HTML; it's a generated one from a clients website and it has a complex hierarchy of XSL files associated with it for the conversion. For example `spl.xsl` references  `spl-common.xsl` which in turn references a number of other XSL files.
I've looked at several means of converting it; tried running `xmlto` on the command line and I get compilation error:

> file /home/name/Downloads/MedicalXmlTransform/xml-verbatim.xsl line 1 element transform xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported

It seems that it doesn't support anything past XSLT 1.0.
I tried running `saxonb-xslt`(XSLT-2.0 processor), but I got the same error.

I tried creating a simple Java application to perform it:

```
import javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class HowToXSLT {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    /*if (args.length != 3)
    {
        System.err.println("give command as follows : ");
        System.err.println("XSLTTest data.xml converted.xsl converted.html");
        return;
    }*/
        String dataXML = "resources/xml/ba97d0d9-67c4-4f45-ae9e-9f4263b9ec62.xml";
        String inputXSL = "resources/xsl/spl.xsl";
        String outputHTML = "resources/xml/output1.html";

        HowToXSLT st = new HowToXSLT();
        try
        {
            st.transform(dataXML, inputXSL, outputHTML);
        }
        catch (TransformerConfigurationException e)
        {
            System.err.println("TransformerConfigurationException");
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        catch (TransformerException e)
        {
            System.err.println("TransformerException");
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void transform(String dataXML, String inputXSL, String outputHTML)
            throws TransformerConfigurationException,
            TransformerException
    {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(inputXSL);
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);
        StreamSource in = new StreamSource(dataXML);
        StreamResult out = new StreamResult(outputHTML);
        transformer.transform(in, out);
        System.out.println("The generated HTML file is:" + outputHTML);
    }
```

Similarly no dice - I got a `ClassCast` exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Param cannot be cast to  com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Variable

I know I'm all over the place with attempting command line solutions and then a Java program - but I just need to get it transformed. The XML itself calls an XSLT file which in turn references 5 others and a few XML files.

It's not as simple as one XSLT file - does anyone out there know how to translate an XML file using an XSLT hierarchy?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your requirement to use XSLT 2.0 is unrelated to any requirement to use a "hierarchy of XSLT files". The xsl:include and xsl:import declarations are hardly changed between XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.

Assuming you do need XSLT 2.0 (for reasons unconnected with this), then running the transformation using Saxon is the right way forward. If you attempted this and it failed, then you need to tell us precisely how you attempted it and precisely how it failed, because you did something wrong and we can't tell what.

If you want to run an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet using the JAXP API, then don't use

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

because this will pick up whatever XSLT processor it finds lying around on the classpath. Instead use

```
TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactorImpl();
```

for Saxon-HE, or

```
TransformerFactory factory = com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseConfigurationFactory();
```

for Saxon-EE. This (a) ensures you get an XSLT processor that meets your processing requirements, and (b) avoids the expensive search of the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for responding so this is my command line for saxon:
user@host:~/Downloads/MedicalXmlTransform$ saxonb-xslt ba97d0d9-67c4-4f45-ae9e-9f4263b9ec62.xml spl.xsl

This is the output:
Warning: at xsl:transform on line 26 column 138 of spl.xsl:
  Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor
Error on line 623 of spl-common.xsl:
  SESU0013: Unsupported HTML version: 1.0
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:/home/user/Downloads/MedicalXmlTransform/spl-common.xsl#107)
     processing /document
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported

Comment: This means that your original problem is solved and you have now moved on to the next (unrelated) problem. If you don't understand how requesting HTML version="1.0" is an error, please raise another question.